# Refresh ListView with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, android-listview, audio-recording, swiperefreshlayout

Hey I'm developing an AudioRecorder App(Im new to Android developing). One "Tab" is to record the file and the other one is to play it. The problem is that the adapter of the list catches the data at Activity start and not after recording. So I try to let the Swiperefreshlayout refresh the data in the onRefresh() method. But I dont get it to work! I think the problem is caused here

```
for (String file:list){
        if (file.endsWith(".3pg")){
            values.add(file);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

in onRefresh().

FragmentAllRecords.java:

```
package com.julian.recorder;


import android.app.LauncherActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentAllRecords extends ListFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private String path;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeLayout;
    private String musicURI;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private CardView mMediaCard;
    private ProgressBar mMediaProgress;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> values;
    private String[] list;




    public FragmentAllRecords() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View p= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_all_records, container, false);
        mSwipeLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout)p.findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
        mSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);



        mMediaCard=(CardView)p.findViewById(R.id.mediaCard);
        mMediaCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mp=new MediaPlayer();



        // Use the current directory as title
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        +File.separator
        +Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC
        +File.separator;
        if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
            path = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        }

        // Read all files sorted into the values-array
        values = new ArrayList<String>();
        File dir = new File(path);
        list = dir.list();
        if (list != null) {
            for (String file : list) {
                if (!file.endsWith(".3pg")) {
                    values.add(file);


                }
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(values);

        // Put the data into the list
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.recording_list_item, R.id.listText, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);





        return p;
    }



    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        mMediaCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        int duration=mp.getDuration();
        int currposition=mp.getCurrentPosition();





        musicURI=path
                +values.get(position);

        mp.getDuration();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(musicURI);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();


    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        values.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        for (String file:list){
            if (file.endsWith(".3pg")){
                values.add(file);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }


}
```

fragment_fragment_all_records.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.julian.recorder.FragmentAllRecords">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipelayout">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/mediaCard">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mStop"
        android:src="@drawable/pause_circle"
        android:background="@drawable/pause_circle"

        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mResume"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/play_circle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/skip_next"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/mNext" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mPrevious"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/skip_previous"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

(Maybe this is needed, too. Dont know...)Mainactivity.java: (I called it RecordingActivity)

```
    package com.julian.recorder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu;
import com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.AddFloatingActionButton;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTab;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabListener;


public class RecordingActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MaterialTabListener{

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    MaterialTabHost tabHost;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);



        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < pagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.addTab(
                    tabHost.newTab()
                            .setText(pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this)
            );
        }






    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recording, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab materialTab) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(materialTab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab materialTab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab materialTab) {

    }





}
```

Comment: Did you check wether the method onRefresh is called? I'm talking about something like System.out.println("onRefresh Method called"); in the onRefresh() method.

Comment: yes, for example toast is working. the values.clear() does work ,too!

Comment: Ok. and do you get something like an error, or is it just not shown in the list?

Comment: just nothing showing. nothing in the logcat and no crash

Comment: files are showing for first time?

Comment: yes and after values.clear() they are away (when i refresh)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have done a mistake in giving the file extension at file.endsWith(".3pg") which should be ".3gp" which is correct extension for your generated audio files.

Comment: This brought back the files but not the one i recorded before... it only catches the old files again...

Comment: Hey, a few years later and I am wondering what the hell I was thinking asking this question... Right, so I wanted to clean up, as this question probably didn't help anyone, no upvotes have been given & it's completely irrelevant on this forum anyway. That's why I'm asking you if you'd be so kind as to self-delete your answer (:/) in order for that to work (one answer max, and the other guy seems fairly inactive). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the solution to the problem. You need to call `dir.list()` again in `onRefresh()`. Something like below:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    values.clear();
    File dir = new File(path);
    list = dir.list();
    for (String file:list){
        if (file.endsWith(".3pg")){
            values.add(file);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

You need to call the `File.list()` again in `onRefresh()`, that is the actual refresh. There is no caching going on here as you suspect. Contents of `list` would be static until you refresh them again. I have also fixed the improper calling of `notifyDataSetChanged()`.